# For Loop With 2 Dimensional List

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a function that tells the user the exits in the room they're in. Each sublist is a room. All non-zero numbers are exits for each sublist in my 2 dimensional list. All zeroes are not exits. I keep getting the output *"There is no exit to room 0"* 4 times in a row when the first value of my map is `[0, 2, 3, 0]` which clearly has 2 and 3 which have an exit. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

```
map=[[0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3]]

class Player:
    def __init__(self, room_number = 0):
        self.room_number = room_number

    def exit_count(self):
        for n in range(0,4):
            if map[self.room_number][n]==0:
                print("There is no exit to room {0}\n".format(self.room_number))
            elif map[self.room_number][n]!=0:
                print("There is an exit to room {0}\n".format(self.room_number))
p = Player()

p.exit_count()
```

Comment: `self.room_number` is the current room, `n` is the exit number. So you should be printing `n`.

Comment: prints 

"There is no exit to room 0

There is an exit to room 0

There is an exit to room 0

There is no exit to room 0" for me

Answer (score 0):

drop the elif condition and just use else since there is no other possible answer. Other than that works

```
map=[[0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 3]]

class Player: 
    def __init__(self, room_number = 0): 
        self.room_number = room_number

    def exit_count(self):
        for n in range(0,4):
            # print n
            # print map[self.room_number][n]
            if map[self.room_number][n] == 0:
                print("There is no exit to room {0}\n".format(self.room_number))
            else:
                print("There is an exit to room {0}\n".format(self.room_number))

p = Player(room_number=4)

p.exit_count()
```

outs

```
There is no exit to room 4

There is an exit to room 4

There is an exit to room 4

There is no exit to room 4

[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following

```
def findexits(rooms):
    for room in rooms:
        yield [door for door in room if door]

exits = findexits(map) # this is a generator
# list(exits) => [[2,3], [..],...]
# If you wish to calculate the number of exits, employ the generator
# before consuming
exit_counts = [len(exit_) for exit_ in exits]
# this consumes it.
```

You can modify `findexits` in all kinds of ways.